# Findin a string in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, search

EDIT: Yeah, I fucked up in the initial question and ithas some important missing information; the list was not a word-by-word list but a list of sentences.

Now, I know this sounds like a common question, but not really.
I want to find a specific string in a list of strings, but ONLY if it's an exact match. For example:

- word to find: `'correct'`
- list: `['this is correct', 'this is corrected', 'stingray for dinner']`

This should find only the first element, but I have tried (and basically other similar configurations):

```py
a = [i for i in list if word in i]
```

This does not work, as 'corrected' contains 'correct'; my output is:

- a = ['this is correct', 'this is corrected']
  instead of what i need:
- a = ['this is correct`]

How do I solve this?

Final comment: My list is much larger and can contain multiple sentences with the word 'correct'. I need them all to process something else. Then I will need all sentences with the word 'corrected' as well, and so on.

ANSWER:
The answer I was looking for would be this:

```py
answer = [i for i in list if any("correct" == j for j in i.split(' ')]
```

Comment: Use string equality `[i for i in array if word == i]` ?

Comment: Can the list contain duplicates? If not, just use `if word in array: a = [word]`

Comment: Use string equality **and make your array a `set`**, otherwise the search will be quadratic.

Comment: Also remember that Python doesn't have "arrays", it has "lists" (which is important, because you can only search for answers if you use the same words that everyone else uses)

Comment: @mozway Unless you're searching for multiple words, it's just O(n)

Comment: having said that, it feels like you're not saying what you _actually_ want to do: you already have the word, so if you want the exact match, that's simply going to give you the _same_ word, so that doesn't let you do anything. Are you looking for the _position_ for match(es)? (because that requires `enumerate`) Or "whether the word is in the list at all"? (because that doesn't even require iterating). Or "how many times the word is in the list"? etc.

Comment: What do you **actually** want to do?  Do you just want to know **if** the word is in the list?  Do you want to find the **location(s)** of the word in the list?

Comment: Yeah, as I said below I fucked up and left out some key information. Answers posted so far do not work, for reasons that will be obvious as soon as I edit

Comment: Is punctuation a factor here?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to do this:

```
input_list = ["this is correct", "this is corrected", "stingray for dinner", "correct me if I'm wrong"]
the_word = "correct"
output_list = [e for e in input_list if the_word in e.split()]
print(output_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['this is correct', "correct me if I'm wrong"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`a = [i for i in array if i == word]`

would do what you're doing, but find the exact match.

The `in` keyword works differently depending on context; you might be thinking of a key `in` a dictionary, but what you've written is looking for a string `in` a string, which is why you get substrings.

This would go through the whole list one by one (even to the end, i.e after you've found the first match).

Edited to include explanation as kindly pointed to by Mike :)

Comment: But see Barmar's comment above for a possible better way.

Comment: Ah, damn, i have checked the answer and I see now that my question is incomplete. That does not work because my array is made of sentences, so the '==' will always be a false. I know the sentences and I  want to divide them into smaller sets by a single word that some can contain.

Comment: You can first `.split()` your sentences to get them into a list of words (and punctuation gotchas). If you're doing analysis of real text, maybe consider something like NLTK.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `re` package.

```py
import re

phrases = ['this is correct', 'this is corrected', 'stingray for dinner']
print([phrase for phrase in phrases if re.findall(r"\bcorrect\b", phrase)])
```

Will give you:

```
['this is correct']
```

Comment: Functionally correct but slow

Comment: @Codist It's a tradeoff. This will find matches like *"the fault that we cannot correct,"* whereas, a `e.split()` will not. If you time this on the complete works of Shakespeare this returns 9 rows in 0.084 seconds and the `e.split()` answer returns 8 rows in 0.056 seconds. I'll leave it to future readers to determine if the extra time is worth it or not.